# Floating point 'error' is php 64bit

Tags: php, rounding

Using the following code:

```
<?php
  $balance = (float)255744.12340511001247912645339965820312;
  print_r($balance);
?>
```

On a 32 bit machine I get:

```
255744.12340511
```

On a 64 bit machine I get.

```
255744.123405
```

I am, (almost), sure that it has nothing to do with 32 vs 64 bit machine but rather that it is a setting somewhere.
I also don't  think it is a floating point issue but rather a php rounding issue.

I would like my precision to go to 16 decimals.

How can I get that level of precision?

Comment: Floating point numbers (in PHP) have a limited precision. But you can increase the current precision using [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/ini_set).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the problem, I will now set the precision when my script is loaded, (or in the ini file but it does not matter either way).

Comment: Thanks, I fully understand that it might or might not work, but your answered my question as to why the values were not the same on both servers. I wanted to confirm that it was a setting in the config rather than a limitation in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer my own question to avoid confusion, as rightly pointed out by,  Amal Murali the setting is:

in the ini file:

```
; The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers.
; http://php.net/precision
precision = 32

; When floats & doubles are serialized store serialize_precision significant
; digits after the floating point. The default value ensures that when floats
; are decoded with unserialize, the data will remain the same.
serialize_precision = 32
```

Or directly in your script

```
ini_set('precision', 32);
ini_set( 'serialize_precision', 32 );
```

If you have access to the configuration it might be slightly faster.